# How to change config file which nuget will transform in order to assembly binding redirects

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I am using xdt transformations in my asp.net mvc project. My web.configs have following structure:

- web.base.config - base config file with shared props/binding redirects etc.
- web.$(configuration).config - config file with xdt transformations for given configuration.
- web.config - output file of XML transformations.

Nuget is sometimes generating assembly binding redirects which are created inside web.config file that is automatically generated by TransformXML. I would like to target `web.base.config` as a file to apply binding redirects. How could I do that?

### What I tried

#### Investigated `GenerateBindingRedirects` target from `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#MSBuildProperty=_GenerateBindingRedirectsIntermediateAppConfig

Basically I tried to see if this is the msbuild target that could take part in assembly binding redirect transformations on *.config files. Unfortunately no as it is transforming `*.dll.config` file in bin folder.

#### Searched nuget2 source from [Github](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2) to find place in source code where config file is being determined

I saw proper file in RuntimeHelpers.cs:63 :

```
var manager = new BindingRedirectManager(fileSystem, project.GetConfigurationFile());
```

Where `GetConfigurationFile` implementation looks like:

```
return project.IsWebProject() ? WebConfig : AppConfig;
```

Where web/app config constants are `web.config` and `app.config`. This is really giving me like 0 hope that I can change config file location for binding redirect resolving with current nuget runtime. Maybe I am wrong and there is still a chance to apply binding redirects to `web.base.config`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to make nuget to patch non-standard config, however I worked a lot with transformations and if you can elaborate a little bit more why you ended up with `web.base.config` for common parts but not `web.config` perhaps someone can help. Set up that worked for my team is keeping `web.config` 'dev ready' to allow developer debug everything locally and apply configuration transforms **only during publishing**. We had 2 types of transforms: configuration (debug/release) and environment specific (dev1/qa2/prod.green).

Comment: +1 to @IlliaPopov's comment about the extra configs being transforms that are used on publish and `web.config` otherwise containing everything. I get the impression that's how it was designed to work, but it's just my feeling. BTW, NuGet2 is ancient, which targeted Visual Studio 2013. The NuGet.Client repo contains all the current code.

Comment: for us, the reason to separate `web.base.config`, `web.xxx.config` and `web.config` is version control. It's error prone to have a constantly changing config file that's checked in to VC. Anyone find an elegant way to fix this?

Comment: @CervEd From what I had seen I think change to nuget would be required to have this functionality.

Nuget source code does not have any property you could check to select to which web.config it should refer :/